# iOS Firebase Objective C UITableView from multiple nodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using the firebase friendly chat example to read a list of news items from a single node into a UITableView, which is working fine.

However I now want to read data in from two nodes:-

1). Firstly read in all items in the news node

2). Then based on the user who is currently logged, highlight news items they have favourited.

My code and firebase database structure are below, my question is what is the best way to achieve this? Do I read the new items into an array then read the favourites based on the user who is logged in and if not null append them to the array?

Any ideas of what is the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Firebase structure

```
"news": {
"one": {
  "name": "Sample New Item",
  "icon": "1.png",
  "timestamp": 1459361875666
},
"two": { ... },
"three": { ... }
},

"users": {
"DZ9sBWCbcbevdnjV3hRcwKq1Urg1": {
"one": {
  "favourite": true
},
"five": {
  "favourite": true
},
"DZ9sBWCbcbevdnjV3hRcwKq1HSrg3": {
"six": {
  "favourite": true
},
```

Code

```
self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

newsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

_refHandle = [[ref child:@"news"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot)
              {
                  [newsArray addObject:snapshot];

                  [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newsArray.count-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                  NSLog(@"%@", snapshot);
              }];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [newsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

FIRDataSnapshot *newsSnapshot = newsArray[indexPath.row];
NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *news = newsSnapshot.value;

UILabel *newsLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
areaLabel.text = news[@"name"];

UIImageView *cellIcon = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
cellIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:news[@"icon"]];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: is star supposed to be for currently logged in user ?

Comment: even tho as i can see you have alot better ways to achieve this above, please check out the firebase iOS Objective C sample you will see there a user, posts, starts etc, exactly what u need here man :).

Comment: Yes, I only want to show stars next to news items for the current logged in user. I can get the current userid and pull back all of the news items which they favourited, but I don't know what the best way is to combine the data from the two nodes (two snapshots) and display it in the tableView.